# How to generate an AES key in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, react-native, encryption, aes

I am trying to use an encryption library in JS that uses AES. How can I generate a secure secret key so that I don't have to hardcode a key in the code (which could be easily seen and used by an attacker)?

NOTE:

Once it is generated I am going to store it in a secure keystore provided by the operating system so that it can be retrieved and used to decrypt information(iOS and Android--I'm using React Native).

Comment: You cant protect a key if its stored clientside.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone if it's stored in iOS/Android keystore it would offer more protection than it being hardcoded in the code right?

Comment: First things first. What data are you trying to protect, and from whom?

Comment: Generally, to securely use a key in a keystore, you generate the key *in* the key store and let the library that comes with the key store do the operations with the key. If you have to import/export the key to RAM all the time then using a key store is less effective.

Comment: @duskwuff personal health data in the app that needs to be encrypted on disk to meet HIPAA guidelines

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Encrypt data in React native (Using Expo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60733815/how-to-encrypt-data-in-react-native-using-expo)