# How to Encrypt data in React native (Using Expo)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, encryption, aes, expo

I'm trying to simply encrypt a message using a given key and iV. I've tried several libraries to achieve this but Expo isn't compatible with any of them. I couldn't find any encryption libraries for Expo (**That support AES**). I guess my question is : **How do I encrypt data in React Native running Expo**

Ps : I am not interested in [expo-crypto](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/crypto/)

Comment: can't you use pure js libs like `crypto-js`?

Comment: @LonelyCpp Not with expo. It produces the following error :   The package at "node_modules/crypto-js/core.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "crypto". It failed because React Native does not include the Node standard library. Read more at https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/faq/#can-i-use-nodejs-packages-with-expo
Failed building JavaScript bundle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Another possibility (what I did) is to use the CryptoES library.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-es

After long search I found it, it is a continued development of the 3.1 version of the CryptoJS library and can be used with Expo.

Comment: Do you have any ideas for using AES-GCM? GCM Mode is not supported in crypto-es.

Answer (score 5):

```
npm i --save crypto-es crypto-js
```

```
import CryptoES from "crypto-es";
```

Then you should encrypt the text, for example:

```
var mytexttoEncryption = "Hello" 
const encrypted = CryptoES.AES.encrypt(mytexttoEncryption ,"your password").toString();

var C = require("crypto-js");

var Decrypted = C.AES.decrypt(E, "your password");
var result =Decrypted.toString(C.enc.Utf8);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use crypto-js@3.1 , 3.1.x version use Math.random() and doesn't require node "crypto" package. It's not as safe as the latest version but works for me.

```
yarn add crypto-js@3.1
```

I only use it for decrypting. If you really need it for some security requirements I suggest you encrypt it in server node enviroment.

Comment: It should be noted that this has a SEVERE security vulnerability and is suseptable to cipher attacks. `npm audit` should show this.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to use `jshashes` for my React-native & Expo project. The goal of this module is to reimplement hash node's crypto functions in pure javascript without dependency on node:

```
yarn add jshashes
```

Answer (score 0):

first use this command :

```
npm i crypto-es
```

then now you should import it with this command :

```
import CryptoES from "crypto-es";
```

then you should encrypt the text :
for example   :

```
var mytexttoEncryption = "Hello" 
const encrypted = CryptoES.AES.encrypt(mytexttoEncryption ,"your password").toString();
```

now for decryption :
install the package of  crypto-js with this command :

```
npm i crypto-js
```

then lets decrypt it

```
var C = require("crypto-js");

 var Decrypted = C.AES.decrypt(E, "your password");
var result =Decrypted.toString(C.enc.Utf8);

console.log(result)
```

so use this it will be ok

Comment: expo-crypto documentation is not good , but you can use crypto-es its nice and you can decrypt it easily with some library like crypto-js and etc

Comment: Do you know if they will support aes gcm mode soon?