# AES Encryption with Expo for React Native

Tags: react-native, encryption, aes, expo

I would like to know how can we encrypt using AES and Expo for react native.

The `expo-crypto` seems to be only providing hashing and no real encryption.

Is there a way to do this with Expo?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Encrypt data in React native (Using Expo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60733815/how-to-encrypt-data-in-react-native-using-expo)

Comment: Check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64305915/5515225